# Chainlink: how to get an array of random numbers?

Tags: solidity, oracles, chainlink, randomness

I'm using Chainlink VRF and its function to get an array of random numbers:

```
function expand(uint256 randomValue, uint256 n) public pure returns (uint256[] memory expandedValues) {
    expandedValues = new uint256[](n);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        expandedValues[i] = uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(randomValue, i)));
    }
    return expandedValues;
}
```

In my case, I want random numbers in [0, 99], so `randomValue` is gonna be 100, always. As far as I know, in order to use this function, firstly, I have to call:

```
function getRandomNumber() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
    require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee, "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet");
    return requestRandomness(keyHash, fee);
}
```

Perfect. But... When I execute `getRandomNumber()` for the second time, I expect to get a different array, right? So why I'm getting the same array even after the second execution of `getRandomNumber()`? Perhaps that `expand()` function is not using the result of `getRandomNumber()`? Is that's the case, what's the logic of `expand()` function? Am I missing something?

**SOLVED: this code is working perfectly:**

```
    function getRandomNumber() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee, "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet");
        return requestRandomness(keyHash, fee);
    }

    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
        randomResult = randomness;
    }

    function expand() internal view returns (uint256[] memory expandedValues) {
        expandedValues = new uint256[](maxRandonNumbers);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < maxRandonNumbers; i++) {
            expandedValues[i] = uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(randomResult, i))) % 100;
        }
        return expandedValues;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get multiple random numbers from a single VRF response, you should create an array where the `randomValue` is your original returned VRF number and `n` is the desired number of random numbers.

If you need to generate a random number within a given range, you should use [modulo](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.0/types.html#modulo) to define the limits of your range, `%100` in your case for `[0,99]`

```js
function expand(uint256 randomValue, uint256 n) public pure returns (uint256[] memory expandedValues) {
    expandedValues = new uint256[](n);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        expandedValues[i] = uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(randomValue, i))) % 100;
    }
    return expandedValues;
}
```